# PHP include external file with specified port

Tags: php, include, port

I am trying to include an external PHP file in my PHP script using the include function, however as soon as I specify a port as part of the URL I get a connection timed out error.

For example:

```
include "http://www.url.com:8090/login.php";
```

As I said it works fine without the port so do I need change a PHP setting or use a different method.

Note: Using port 80 is not an option.

Comment: _NEVER_ include remote files!

Comment: ... unless you're damned sure you know exactly what you're doing. And have some degree of control over both servers. It's just one of those things that can go horribly wrong. In either case, I'm not sure include supports ports.

Comment: I have full control over both servers and can restrict access to the remote file to the calling server only.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(@fsockopen("serverurl", port, $errno, $errstr, 1)){ 
    include('serverurl/file.extension');
}
```